# Netbeans settings synchronization

Tags: netbeans, synchronization, settings

Is there any way how to synchronize the Netbeans settings across multiple working stations (ie. PC and Laptop). Its about project settings (FTP accouns), installed plugins and other settings (like colors).

What are you thoughts and experiences?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: I was planning to have a way to sync the whole netbeans home dir. Not sure if that will work.

Comment: Netbeans needs a installed Java, which may differ between platforms, so this may be a issue. Let me know about your experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You can Export your settings to a zip file and import it at other locations.

Export: **`Tools -> Options -> Export`** (Import is the same way).